Error creating bean Spring boot
При запуске Spring Boot приложение исключение:
Caused by: NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dayz.database.Dotawiki.repository.ItemRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="itemRepository")}


Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.dayz.database.Dotawiki.repository.ItemRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="itemRepository")}

Item Repository:
    @Repository
    public interface ItemRepository {

    Item getItemByIdAndType(Long itemId, String itemType);

    @Query("SELECT i.name FROM Illnesses i")
    List<String> findAllIllnessNames();

    }

ItemsController:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/illnessesNames")
public class ItemsController {

    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ItemsController(@Qualifier("itemRepository") ItemRepository itemRepository) {
        this.itemRepository = itemRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    private List<String> getAllNamesIllnesses() {
        return itemRepository.findAllIllnessNames();
    }
}

Один из наследников ItemRepository:
@Repository
public interface IllnessesRepository extends JpaRepository<Illnesses, Long>, ItemRepository {
    Illnesses getByIdAndType(Long id, String type);
}

Item:
public interface Item {
    String getName();
    Long getId();
    String getType();
}

Illnesses:
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "illnesses")
public class Illnesses implements Item {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String causes;

    private String symptoms;

    private String treatment;

    private String type;
}

applicationContext.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dayz.database.Dotawiki"/>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
        <property name="viewNames" value="*.html,*.xhtml" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="templateResolver"
          class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="classpath:/templates/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
    </bean>
</beans>

pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>your.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Your Application Name</name>
    <description>Your application description</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.15.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jr-objects</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.34</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <scope>annotationProcessor</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>


При создании класса и бина ItemRepositoryImpl  ошибок нет но реализовать методы ItemRepository в java class`е сложно можно ли сделать без создание impl

Ну так ItemRepository и не надо помечать аннотацией @Repository, зачем? Отмечайте только те репозитории, которые имплементируют JpaRepository и ему подобные.

Если убрать аннотацию ошибка не пропадёт бин не создается

Использовать аннотацию @Qualifier с репозиториями вообще такая себе история, поскольку Spring динамически предоставляет их скрытые реализации, и поэтому лучше оперировать конкретными интерфейсами. То есть, в вашем случае, внедрять IllnessesRepository. Тем не менее, если хотите всё же через родительский интерфейс, можете в аннотации @Qualifier попробовать указать название illnessesRepository.

заработало просто убрал аннотацию и поменял название репо в @Qualifier можете сказать книги, видео, или статьи где можно почитать об этом по глубже и понять как всё работает

Паттерн Dependency injection (DI), начните с него, а потом в любой книге по спрингу ищете реализацию этого паттерна. Тогда станут понятны ошибки как в вопросе.

Вы использовали два подхода обращения к БД одновременно:

Через интерфейс+класс аннотированный @Repository.
Через специальный интерфейс JpaRepository из твоей зависимости    spring-data-jpa.

в первом подходе создается бин через наш интерфейс, а реализацией будет наш КЛАСС который мы и аннотируем @Repository.
во втором - создается бин через спринговый интерфейс JpaRepository.
Так и получается, что из-за такой записи спринг сходит с ума:
@Repository
public interface IllnessesRepository extends JpaRepository<Illnesses, Long>, ItemRepository

Как можно поступить?
Классов вы не создавали, так что предположу, что вы решили использовать spring-data-jpa.
Уберите все аннотации @Repository, и в IllnessesRepository не
наследуйтесь от ItemRepository.
